# smtpmail-send-it: authentication failed in response to AUTH PLAIN (emacs + mu4e + posteo)

Tags: emacs, smtp

I've been trying to set of my new posteo.net email account on emacs/mu4e (I have a gmail account that works on emacs/mu4e but would like to switch).  I can successfully receive emails via offlineimap but cannot send emaisl.  Specifically, I get the following error message:

```
smtpmail-send-it: Sending failed: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: in response to AUTH PLAIN
```

I have the following variables set in emacs:

```
  smtpmail-stream-type         'starttls
  smtpmail-default-smtp-server "posteo.net"
  smtpmail-smtp-server         "posteo.net"
  smtpmail-smtp-service        587)
```

I tried a few other combinations, i.e., posteo.de, smtp.posteo.net, smtp.posteo.de, as well as using ssl for smtpmail-stream-type (along with port=465), all failing with the same message. Any tips would be welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was answered here: [Cannot send email in emacs via smtpmail + starttls](https://superuser.com/questions/1481296/cannot-send-email-in-emacs-via-smtpmail-starttls/1485836?noredirect=1#comment2243278_1485836)

The .authinfo file needs to include the full email address, not just the username, as login.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar trouble, the solution being to set the following variables:

```
(setq smtpmail-smtp-user           "username@posteo.net"
      smtpmail-default-smtp-server "posteo.de"
      smtpmail-smtp-server         "posteo.de"
      smtpmail-smtp-service        587
      smtpmail-stream-type         'starttls
      smtpmail-use-gnutls          t)
```

when prompted for your SMTP username and password it will look odd (username@posteo.net@posteo.de) but it worked for me.

hope that helps