# Cannot send email in emacs via smtpmail + starttls

Tags: emacs, smtp, gnutls

I cannot send emails in emacs via smtpmail with starttls.  Here are my configs:

```
  smtpmail-stream-type         'starttls
  smtpmail-default-smtp-server "posteo.de"
  smtpmail-smtp-server         "posteo.de"
  smtpmail-smtp-service        587
```

And here is the debug output:

```
220 submission02.posteo.de ESMTP Postfix
250-submission02.posteo.de
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 76800000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
250-submission02.posteo.de
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 76800000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
AUTH PLAIN <omitted>
535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: 
QUIT
221 2.0.0 Bye

Process smtpmail connection broken by remote peer
```

Any suggestions what is going on would be great -- thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using mu4e (and a posteo service...)

my working config has :

```
(setq mu4e-sent-folder "/Sent"
      mu4e-drafts-folder "/Drafts"
      mu4e-trash-folder "/Trash"
      message-send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it
      user-mail-address "foo@posteo.net"
      user-full-name  "Foo buzz"
      smtpmail-default-smtp-server "smtp.posteo.de"
      smtpmail-smtp-server "posteo.de"
      smtpmail-stream-type 'starttls
      smtpmail-smtp-service 587)
```

Don't forget to:
`(require 'smtpmail)`

Comment: Thanks! I copied your setting but still had the same error. Do you have any specific encryption settings for tls?

Comment: I use `offlineimap` and in my `offlineimaprc` file I have the preference: `sslcacertfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`

Comment: Thanks -- I have the same in my offlineimaprc, but getting emails is also not the problem; it is sending them via smtpmail.

Comment: Do you use .authinfo

Comment: I found the error -- the .authinfo file needs to include the full email address, not just the username, as login.  This is different from gmail, where the username is fine. Thank you for your help!